# Advice For The Grey Month

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

I know that the schengen visa 90 days in 180 days policy has already been greatly discussed but once again I am caught in this problem.

I am originally from Taiwan (I have the 90 days without going to embassy). I am currently applying for my Master Degree with universities in Holland and Germany.

From 02/01/19 through 22/03/19, I have to be in Berlin, DE for intensive German lessons. I will have university interviews on 15,16,17/January and in April/May.

I was denied the "Prepare to Study" Visa for Germany which brings me to my problem now... I am missing a month no matter how I calculte the days. I would love some suggestions on how I can deal with this. The more I read the more confuse I am.

Am I allow to stop the 90 days by going out of Schengen and reentering again on my interview days in April/May? If so, do I need to inform or get reentry visa stamp?

Or is it that once I leave in March (after 81 days stay) , I have to return in July? If so, how can I avoid this?

I feel it is not wise for me to fly back to Asia, what are some of the cheapest non-Schengen areas I can travel to and live in for this grey period?

Thank you so much in advance for all suggestions!

Comment: The format here does not allow for multiple questions. Edit your question into one overarching question.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't really understood how the 90/180 rule works, see: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work

Answer (score 2):

The 90/180 rule for the Schengen area counts individual days (partial days count full). So by leaving you "stop the clock" as far as this rule is concerned.

Your passport should get stamped whenever you enter or leave the Schengen area. It may be that some immigration checkpoints are lazy about the exit stamps. You can remind them that you need the stamp.

A cheap place outside Schengen is really difficult to answer, I suspect that a flight home will be cheaper. The Balkans, maybe?

Comment: Turkey comes to mind.